# Pagination Tableview Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, pagination

I am new to ios development. I want to load large amount of data in tableview using pagination.when new page is loaded i am appending data to "myMainList" and reloading the tableview , but it seems not a good way of loading more data.I could not be able to find a good solution in swift.

I got a pagination object in my json response.

```
{
"pagination" : {
"total" : 13,
"last_page" : 2,
"per_page" : 10,
"next_page_url" : null,
"current_page" : 2,
"prev_page_url" : "http:\/\/xxxxxxxxxxxx/page=1"
}
}
```

Here is my code.Hope you understand my problem.Looking for a good solution.Thanks in Advance.

```
var pagenationURL = ""
var myMainList : [MyModel] = []
var rowCount : Int = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let parameters = ["token":NetworkingUtil.getUserToken()]
    callWebService(parameters: parameters)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let lastItem = rowCount-1
    if(indexPath.row) == lastItem {
        loadMoreData()
    }
}


func loadMoreData(){
    let parameters = ["token":NetworkingUtil.getUserToken()]

    if(pagenationURL.isEmpty){
        print("end of page")
    }
    else{
        callWebService1(parameters: parameters)
    }
}

func callWebService(parameters : [String : String]) {
Alamofire.request(Common.getMyExpense(), method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: NetworkingUtil.getAlamoFireHeader()).responseJSON { (Response) in
    let error = Response.result.error
    let req = Response.request
    let res = Response.response
    let json = Response.data
    if error != nil {
        if req != nil && res != nil {
            print(req!)
            print(res!)
        }
    }else{
        var parsedjson : JSON!;
        do {
            parsedjson = try JSON(data : json!)
            print(parsedjson)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

     else{
            let myExpensejson = parsedjson["results"]
            self.pagenationURL = parsedjson["pagination"]["next_page_url"].stringValue
            let lostkeyrequestscount : Int = myExpensejson.count
            self.rowCount = lostkeyrequestscount
            self.myMainList = []

            for(_,keylist): (String,JSON) in myExpensejson
            {
                let status = lostkeylist["status"].stringValue
                let date = lostkeylist["date"].stringValue
                let keyObject = MyExpenseModel(status: status, date: date)
                self.myMainList.append(keyObject)
                self.tableview.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
}

func callWebService1(parameters : [String : String]) {
  Alamofire.request(pagenationURL, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: NetworkingUtil.getAlamoFireHeader()).responseJSON { (Response) in
    let error = Response.result.error
    let req = Response.request
    let res = Response.response
    let json = Response.data
    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
    if error != nil {
        if req != nil && res != nil {
            print(req!)
            print(res!)
        }
    }else{
        var parsedjson : JSON!;
        do {
            parsedjson = try JSON(data : json!)
            print(parsedjson)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
      else{
            let myExpensejson = parsedjson["results"]
            self.pagenationURL = parsedjson["pagination"]["next_page_url"].stringValue


            let lostkeyrequestscount : Int = myExpensejson.count
            self.rowCount = lostkeyrequestscount+self.rowCount

            for(_,keylist): (String,JSON) in myExpensejson
            {
                let status = lostkeylist["status"].stringValue
                let date = lostkeylist["date"].stringValue
                let keyObject = MyExpenseModel(status: status, date: date)
                self.myMainList.append(keyObject)
                self.tableview.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used for pagination or infinite scroll an package written in Objective-C. It help me very much.

Package: [UIScrollView+InfiniteScroll](https://github.com/pronebird/UIScrollView-InfiniteScroll)

How to use:

```
// add inifinite scroll
self.tableView.addInfiniteScroll { [unowned self] (tableView) in
  self.loadMore()
}
//  Preload more data 800pt before reaching the bottom of scroll view.
self.tableView.infiniteScrollTriggerOffset = 800
```

In function **loadMore**, I load items from server and I save current page.

I hope to help you with my answer above!

Answer (score 0):

It is not only your problem, server-side must be improved firstly. 
I solved this problem by giving offset in parameters.

```
var offset = 0
let params: Parameters = [... , "offset": offset]
```

every time loads more, offset increases by 10  `//for your case, it is 10`

loads first 10, then the second 10 and so on.

discuss with server-side developers, they know it.

Comment: Thank you BatyrCan